# Architectural Window Glass - White or Black circle in IOR Reflection

Tags: shaders, glass, windows, reflection

[image: large white circle partly visible in window when I chenge Frenel value.]I have modelled a window using a glass that has thickness (about 10mm). Normals face the correct way.

I have researched glass shaders to make sure light passes throught the material and also keeps relections based on the angle to object.

My issues is that I get a White Circle that appears when viewing the glass head on. The circle changes in size related to IOR I have set.

If I make the IOR in the material settings higher the circle gets smaller but the reflections get weaker! I want reflections as it looks nice BUT I don't want a big white circle in my glass reflection.

I think this is all related to IOR.

Does anyone know what this circle is? it appears even when I just light the scene with the default HDRI enviroment textures and have no other lights.

***White Circle is the circle in the glass window******

Thank you for any help.
Ian[image: window glass circle in reflection IOR - my setup]

Comment: where is the white circle? is it the white background?

Comment: Are you talking about the "fireflies"?

Comment: White Circle is the circle in the glass window. Its not part of my model and is annoying. The circle is not pure white. Its quite big.

Comment: If you plug the Fresnel node straight into the output, (or Node Wrangler Shift-click the node)  I suspect you will see that _is_ the circle.. the boundary, dependent on angle of view, and IOR, between refraction and reflection.

Comment: I’m pretty sure he’s talking about the 3D cursor.
You can shift + rmb anywhere to place it somewhere else or simply disable it in the viewport overlay settings at the top (next to the render views)

Comment: Have changed the Fresnel value and the white circle is now bigger and can be seen in the window glass reflection. I don't want this but I want some real life reflections in my windows of the environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange sphere in my glass surfaces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220099/strange-sphere-in-my-glass-surfaces)

Comment: Old post but I had this problem too a while ago. The white circle is a reflection of your light. Point light, spot light or whatever it is.
[See this video how to remove it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IjEXE70ujI)