# Strange sphere in my glass surfaces?

Tags: glass

I'm using Glass nodes from Blender Gurus tutorial but for some reason I get this strange sphere in all my glass surfaces. If I Enable Backface Culling in material settings, the sphere disappears from Viewport reflections but still shows in final renders.

Here is the node setup and a screenshot of the artifact:

[image]

[image]

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: which tutorial?

Comment: @ETHANDAY https://youtu.be/KyXRBu7gn2o?t=300

Comment: It's a result of the insanely high Fresnel value he uses for this "hack". Change the Fresnel and you'll see the sphere change size.

Comment: Hmm okay.. But when I change the Fresnel to small it's not transparent anymore as all I get is reflections. I guess I need to find a new glass material :)

Comment: Yeah. Keep in mind he uses this for a very special-use case. If your scene doesn't need it, there are other options.

Comment: Thanks Christopher! I'll look into other options :)

Answer (score 1):

As Christopher suggested in the comments, this glass hack has too high Fresnel value that is causing the issue. I'll use a different glass node setup.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a simplified setup:

[image]

You can use the *Value* of the *Transparent BSDF* to control the amount of shadow.

[image]

I have a more in-depth answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219303/glass-casting-shadows-and-not-looking-real) that may help as well.

Comment: Thanks Allen, I actually ended up with the same nodes and it seems to work great! The only thing I could not achieve with this new setup is to make it transparent and reflective in Viewport Shading mode as I was able to do it with the previous setup above. Any suggestions on this? I work a lot in the Shading mode and not seeing anything through the windows makes it hard to work on scenes.